# Regarding process related issues in node js and mongo db

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am a novice programmer in Node JS. I have a few queries regarding process related issues like locking and race conditions in Node JS and Mongo DB.

My codes are working perfectly in local environment,but when I am moving to production and come across large number of requests,I might encounter certain issues.

1. How do we avoid write level race conditions for mongo slaves located in different regions? ie say one piece of data is being written locally but the true value for it is being written remotely that is delayed
2. Consider we have node processes located regionally would it need to hit mongo master located in another region which then routes the request to a regional slave? This considerably increases the latency of each write - how do we avoid this? Can we have direct writes to regional slaves from local processes and some kind of replication to maintain data consistency?

I use a Node REST api and use mongoose as the Mongo DB driver.Any help would be deeply appreciated .Thank you .

Comment: It's better to ask just one question at a time.

Comment: @JohnnyHK ,Thanks for the comment.I have cut short into two major queries.Please help if you could.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MongoDB's automatic failover and high availability features are provided by what's called [replication](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/replication-introduction/). The standard MongoDB terms are "primary" for master and "secondary" for slave, so I'll use those terms to be consistent with the documentation and the user base at large. I think both of your questions are answered by one fact: in a replica set, the primary is the only member that accepts writes from clients, ever. The secondaries get the data replicated to them asynchronously a short time later. To answer the questions directly:

1. No writes to slaves except internal replication of writes from the primary, so no "race condition" with writes can arise.
2. All writes must go to the primary. The replication system will distribute to data to the secondaries asynchronously. You can read from secondaries, but it isn't a best practice despite its occasional utility. I'd suggest reading about replica set [read preference](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/read-preference/) and reading [Asya Kamsky's blog post](http://askasya.com/post/canreplicashelpscaling) about scaling with replica sets before deciding to read from secondaries.

Comment: @wdberkeley.Thanks for help. If I use MongoHQ as a service for MongoDB,do I need to worry about these issues -i.e will they manage the replication? Any code level changes in node is required for replication??

Comment: I'm not 100% on what MongoHQ does and I don't want to make promises for them, but MongoDB drivers should invisibly handle dealing with a replica set so that your application doesn't know about it beyond setting options like read preference. Your application will need to handle the short period of downtime that can happen if the primary goes down and a new primary must be elected (of course, this is much better than the indefinite period of downtime that could happen with a standalone :D)